# week start array javascript till X days

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

I have a logic issue with the week start. Here is a code sample below.

```js
WeekStarts(WeekN) {
  let WeekBD = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
  let ArrIndex = WeekBD.findIndex(WeekN);    
    
  for (let u = 0; u < WeekBD.length; u++) {
    if (ArrIndex == 6) {
 
    } else {
    
    }
  }
    
}
```

As if i select from the drop-down which has **Monday to Sunday** as value now i want to select from that day till **5 days a week**.
E.g. as if i select Saturday as the start day of the week then its total 5 days would be Saturday till Wednesday that is 5 days total not 7.

Comment: So your `u` needs to start out as the index of the first day, and then you need to loop until you have 5 of them.  If you reach the end of the loop before you get five, start over at 0.

Comment: If you want just two days, the starting day and the ending day, then you already have your `ArrIndex` for the start day.  And then the end day is just `(ArrIndex + 5) % 7` for it's index.

Answer (score 0):

Please try th code below:

```
    function WeekStarts(WeekN) {
         let WeekBD = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
        let ArrIndex = WeekBD.indexOf(WeekN);    
        var i = 1;

        while(i <= 5){
           if(ArrIndex > 6){ ArrIndex = 0 };
           console.log(WeekBD[ArrIndex]);
          i++;
          ArrIndex++;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you can use the `modulo (%)` operator if you want to find just start / end days

```js
const getDaysFrom = (weekday, noOfDays) => {
  const weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
  , weekdayIndex = weekdays.indexOf(weekday)

  console.log(
    "Start:", weekday, 
    "Days:", noOfDays, 
    "End:", weekdays[(weekdayIndex + noOfDays - 1) % weekdays.length] 
  )
}

getDaysFrom('Saturday', 5)
getDaysFrom('Thursday', 2)
getDaysFrom('Tuesday', 6)
getDaysFrom('Friday', 4)
```